# Should a second, short edit be awarded with reputation points?

Tags: discussion, editing, reputation

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/172494/18510).

I edited an answer. This edit was accepted, and I was granted 2 reputation points. Thirty minutes later, I realized that I made a small mistake. So I re-edited the question. This edit was accepted again, earning another 2 reputation points.

While I'm grateful for these last two reputation points, I'm wondering whether they were really necessary. Should a second, short edit like this be awarded with reputation points?

Answer (score 4):

Lets call a spade a spade, shall we?

An edit is an edit, no matter how small, as long as it's valid. Doesn't make a difference to me. Once we start to make it complicated, then we never know the rules, and one of the nicest things about Stack Exchange is that it's simple.